# How to iterate through a loops and compare substrings with multiple values in cypress

Tags: cypress

I have a search field that compares and retrieves values matching with name or email. I want to iterate through both name list and email list and should match with anyone of them. How can this be achieved?

This is what I tried that I can compare with one of the list :

```
 cy.getEmails().each(($element) => {
         cy.wrap($el).should('have,text', "some value")
  })
```

How can we compare the string with a list of items from cy.getEmails() and cy.getNames()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match any item in a list, use `oneOf` comparison

```js
const names = ['some value', 'another value', ...]
cy.getEmails().each(($element) => {
  cy.wrap($el)
    .invoke('text')
    .should('be.oneOf', names)  
})
```

With `getNames()`

```js
cy.getNames().then(names => {
  cy.getEmails().each(($element) => {
    cy.wrap($el)
      .invoke('text')
      .should('be.oneOf', names)  
  })
})
```

With lower-level javascript Array methods

```js
cy.getNames().then(names => {
  cy.getEmails().each(($element) => {
    matches = names.some(name => $el.text() === name)  // true if any match
    expect(matches).to.eq(true)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the index value you can access `cy.getNames()` elements something like:

```js
cy.getEmails().each(($element, index) => {
  cy.wrap($el).should('have,text', 'some value')
  cy.getNames().eq(index).should('have,text', 'some value')
})
```